# Experimenting with KVM and the kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kvm

I want to experiment with the KVM module and the kernel, for example, how it preforms if I change the implementation of the linked list (defined in [/include/linux/list.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/list.h)) and such. This is not what I'm really doing but good enough to explain my problem.

So what I have done is following [this tutorial](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Code) and before running `make sync; make` I just inserted one line in `virt/kvm/kvm_main.c` at line 500 (just after the list_add macro is used) I added `printk(KERNINFO, "here\n");`. This one I could see just fine with `dmesg`. But inside the file `list.h` in function `list_add`. I also added a line `printk(KERNINFO, "here 2\n");` which did not appear.

So, what is happening? is it linking parts back to the real kernel?

For simplicity, here are the actions I did:

```
git clone git://git.kiszka.org/kvm-kmod.git
cd kvm-kmod
git submodule update --init
./configure [--kerneldir=linux]
#### add the printk to the files.
make sync
make
```

- For those of you who will take the time to do the test, first of all thanks, secondly, `git submodule update --init` will download a lot, so it will take time. and the `make` will compile a lot, so it will also take a few minutes.